# QT QmlMap PolyLine with points

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I have a QML map embeded in widgets application. I plot markers for assets that I am tracking on the MAP with a MapQuickItem. Further I plot a line of the history of previous track point. As items can be added and removed by the operator, I like to contain the map items and history trail as groups so that I can easily delete the map items related to an asset.

I am new to QML and to an extend JS so have done my learning via trial and error.

What I would like to do is to add a marker on each point of the polyline (except last point which is the actual asset marker). The marker on each of these points is also an image (maybe small arrow). I want to rotate this arrow according to the direction of movement as well.

So I have my Main.qml file that does the map drawing etc. Then I have MapMarker.Qml that draws the marker of the actual asset. At the moment the image is hardcoded. Then I have an AssetTrails.qml file which at the moment is only a Polyline component. I am hoping that I can add the point marker to this trail, since then it would be easy to delete all the items when removing.

Can someone perhaps explain to me how to go about this? Is this possible?

I attach my QML snippets for reference. I realise this is not very nice code, but like I said, I learned through trial and error.

**Main.qml functions**

```
function addAsset(location, Name)
{
    // Load the map marker.
    var mapmarkercomp = Qt.createComponent("mapmarker.qml");
    assetMarkers.push(mapmarkercomp.createObject(
                          map, {"coordinate": QtPositioning.coordinate(location.latitude,
                                                                       location.longitude)}));

    if (mapLoadErrorHandler(assetMarkers[assetMarkers.length - 1]))
    {
        map.center = QtPositioning.coordinate(location.latitude,
                                              location.longitude);
        map.zoomLevel = 6;
        assetMarkers[assetMarkers.length - 1].name = Name;
        assetMarkers[assetMarkers.length - 1].followMe = true;
        assetMarkers[assetMarkers.length - 1].transparency = 0;
        map.addMapItem(assetMarkers[assetMarkers.length - 1]);
    }
}
function addAssetHistory(assetPath, assetName, Colour)
{
    // Load the polyline asset trail.
    var polylinecomp = Qt.createComponent("mapassettrail.qml");
    assetTrails.push(polylinecomp.createObject(map, {"line.color": Colour}));
    if (mapLoadErrorHandler(assetTrails[assetTrails.length - 1]))
    {
        assetTrails[assetTrails.length - 1].path = assetPath;
        assetTrails[assetTrails.length - 1].objectName = assetName;
        map.addMapItem(assetTrails[assetTrails.length - 1]);
    }
}
function removeAssetHistory(assetName)
{
    // loop through the assetTrails to find object with the correct asset name and then remove it
    var rr;
    for (rr in assetTrails)
    {
        if (assetTrails[rr].objectName === assetName)
        {
            map.removeMapItem(assetTrails[rr]);
            break;
        }
    }
    assetTrails.splice(rr,1);
}
function updateAssetHistory(assetPath, assetName)
{
    // find the relevant asset trail for the assetName
    var rr;
    for (rr in assetTrails)
    {
        if (assetTrails[rr].objectName === assetName)
        {
            assetTrails[rr].path = ( assetPath);
        }
    }
}
```

**MapMarker.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtLocation 5.9
import QtPositioning 5.6
import AssetStruct 1.0

MapQuickItem
{
    property int spatialPointHeight: 60
    id: assetMapItem2
    property var name: ""
    property var followMe: false
    property var transparency: 0.5
    anchorPoint.x: assetIcon2.width/2
    anchorPoint.y: assetIcon2.height/2
    visible: true
    sourceItem: Column
    {
        Image
        {
            id: assetIcon2
            sourceSize.width: spatialPointHeight
            sourceSize.height: spatialPointHeight
            width: spatialPointHeight
            height: spatialPointHeight
            // Fade out all icons except for the last one
            opacity: 1 - assetMapItem2.transparency
            source: "qrc:/chopper.png"
            transform: Rotation
            {
                id: assetRotation2
                origin.x: spatialPointHeight/2
                origin.y: spatialPointHeight/2
                angle: 90
            }
        }
        Text
        {
            text: name
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            font.bold: true
            width: assetIcon2.width + 10
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted:
    {
        // map.addMapItem(assetMapItem2);
    }
}
```

**AssetTrail.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtLocation 5.9
import QtPositioning 5.6
import AssetStruct 1.0

MapPolyline
{
    id: assetPolylineTrail
    line.color: "green"
    line.width: 3
}
```

So to explain what I want to do a little bit more. See the image below. The asset tracked is called Orion1. Its current position is where the Chopper is located. Its travelled history trail is the purple line. It is not possible to see on this line where the previous reports were there were many in this image, so i want to add an "image" of dot/arrow for each point on the polyline. If the image is an arrow, I can use rotate to also indicate the reported direction.

[image: Image of Orion being tracked]

Comment: Is is possible to add files here? Can I PM you the files?

Comment: private mail, I added some more description of what I am looking for.

Answer (score 5):

From what I have understood you have a set of points and some of them must be part of a `MapPolyline` and one is used with `MapQuickItem`.

The advisable thing is to handle the data through models, and I think that you handle more C++ than `QML` so it would also be a good option for that. In this I have created an item that stores a name, the asset coordinate and a list of coordinates of the history. The model that inherits from `QAbstractListModel` is able to add elements, this model is used by several `MapItemView` that manages the `MapPolyline` and `MapQuickItem`.

```
//assetitem.h

#ifndef ASSETITEM_H
#define ASSETITEM_H

#include <QColor>
#include <QGeoCoordinate>
#include <QString>

class AssetItem{
public:
    QString name() const;
    void setName(const QString &name);

    QGeoCoordinate asset() const;
    void setAsset(const QGeoCoordinate &asset);

    void appendHistory(const QGeoCoordinate &value);
    QList<QGeoCoordinate> getHistory() const;

    QColor getColor() const;
    void setColor(const QColor &color);

private:
    QString mName;
    QGeoCoordinate mAsset;
    QList<QGeoCoordinate> history;
    QColor mColor;
};

#endif // ASSETITEM_H


//assetitem.cpp


#include "assetitem.h"

QString AssetItem::name() const
{
    return mName;
}

void AssetItem::setName(const QString &name)
{
    mName = name;
}

QGeoCoordinate AssetItem::asset() const
{
    return mAsset;
}

void AssetItem::setAsset(const QGeoCoordinate &asset)
{
    if(mAsset.isValid())
        appendHistory(mAsset);
    mAsset = asset;
}

void AssetItem::appendHistory(const QGeoCoordinate &value)
{
    history<< value;
}

QList<QGeoCoordinate> AssetItem::getHistory() const{
    return history;
}

QColor AssetItem::getColor() const
{
    return mColor;
}

void AssetItem::setColor(const QColor &color)
{
    mColor = color;
}

//assetlistmodel.h

#ifndef ASSETLISTMODEL_H
#define ASSETLISTMODEL_H

#include "assetitem.h"

#include <QAbstractListModel>

class AssetListModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    using QAbstractListModel::QAbstractListModel;

    enum AirportsRoles{
        NameRole = Qt::UserRole + 1,
        AssetRole,
        HistoryRole,
        ColorRole
    };

    Q_INVOKABLE bool addAsset(QGeoCoordinate coord, const QString & name);
    bool createAsset(QGeoCoordinate coord, const QString & name);

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const override;
    bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role) override;
private:
    QList<AssetItem> mAssets;
};

#endif // ASSETLISTMODEL_H

//assetlistmodel.cpp

#include "assetlistmodel.h"

bool AssetListModel::addAsset(QGeoCoordinate coord, const QString &name)
{
    auto it = std::find_if(mAssets.begin(), mAssets.end(), [&](AssetItem const& obj){
            return obj.name() == name;
} );
    if(it != mAssets.end()){
        //append
        int row = it - mAssets.begin();
        QModelIndex ix = index(row);
        return  setData(ix, QVariant::fromValue(coord), AssetRole);
    }
    else{
        //create
        return createAsset(coord, name);
    }
}

bool AssetListModel::createAsset(QGeoCoordinate coord, const QString &name)
{
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());

    AssetItem it;
    it.setName(name);
    it.setAsset(coord);
    it.setColor(QColor(qrand()%255, qrand()%255, qrand()%255));
    mAssets<< it;
    endInsertRows();
    return true;
}


int AssetListModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(parent)
    return mAssets.count();
}

QVariant AssetListModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();
    if(index.row() >= 0 && index.row()<rowCount()){
        const AssetItem &it = mAssets[index.row()];
        if(role==NameRole)
            return it.name();
        else if (role == AssetRole)
            return  QVariant::fromValue(it.asset());
        else if(role == HistoryRole){
            QVariantList history_list;
            QList<QGeoCoordinate> coords = it.getHistory();
            for(const QGeoCoordinate & coord: coords){
                history_list<<QVariant::fromValue(coord);
            }
            return history_list;
        }
        else if(role == ColorRole){
            return it.getColor();
        }
    }
    return QVariant();
}


QHash<int, QByteArray> AssetListModel::roleNames() const
{
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
    roles[NameRole] = "name";
    roles[AssetRole]= "asset";
    roles[HistoryRole] = "history";
    roles[ColorRole] = "color";
    return roles;
}

bool AssetListModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role)
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return false;
    if(index.row() >= 0 && index.row()<rowCount()){
        if (role == AssetRole) {
            QGeoCoordinate new_asset(value.value<QGeoCoordinate>());
            mAssets[index.row()].setAsset(new_asset);
            emit dataChanged(index, index, QVector<int>{AssetRole});
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "assetlistmodel.h"

#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include<QQmlContext>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    AssetListModel model;
    QGeoCoordinate coord(41.97732, -87.90801);
     model.addAsset(coord, "testing_name1");
     model.addAsset(coord, "testing_name2");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("assetmodel", &model);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtLocation 5.6
import QtPositioning 5.5

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visibility: "FullScreen"

    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Map {
        id: mapOfWorld
        anchors.centerIn: parent;
        anchors.fill: parent
        zoomLevel: 10
        plugin: Plugin {name: "osm"}
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(41.97732, -87.90801)//KORD

        MapItemView {
            model: assetmodel
            delegate: AssetTrail{
                path: history
                line.color: color
            }
        }

        MapItemView {
            model: assetmodel
            delegate: MapMarker{
                coordinate: asset
            }
        }
    }

    // testing
    property var last_pos1: mapOfWorld.center
    property var last_pos2: mapOfWorld.center

    Timer {
        interval: 500; running: true; repeat: true
        onTriggered: {
            last_pos1 = QtPositioning.coordinate(last_pos1.latitude + 0.1*(Math.random()-0.5),
                                                last_pos1.longitude + 0.1*(Math.random()-0.5))
            assetmodel.addAsset(last_pos1, "testing_name1")
            last_pos2 = QtPositioning.coordinate(last_pos2.latitude + 0.1*(Math.random()-0.5),
                                                last_pos2.longitude + 0.1*(Math.random()-0.5))
            assetmodel.addAsset(last_pos2, "testing_name2")
        }
    }

}
```

<sub>The complete example can be found in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/49727462).</sub>

[image]

Comment: Yes, you are right that I would rather use more C++ and less QML. I do have a model, but i do not think it is a good one. Anyway, your solution would probably be better and simpler. In your image, you have two items and the history for them; the one thing I wanted to add was the mapquickitem on each of the different points on that history line.

Comment: I remembered now that I struggled a lot to get the List of coordinates (in C++ model) to populate the polyline. I could not get the polyline to draw from the QList model. Anyway, I try it again. Nothing to lose.

Comment: I am sorry, I was away on business and have not tried it yet. I will report ASAP

Comment: I think you did a great job to make it much simpler. So I have a few questions: I see in the main.qml there is two MapItemView objects, one for the trail and one for the marker. That makes sense to me and I can see it displays as I expect. This portion I could already do, although not nearly as nice as your solution.

The part that I would like to add is to have another type of marker that is placed on each point of the trail, and then the marker is also rotated according to the direction the asset is traveling in. **Can you show me how to do that?**

Comment: The other thing I see is that you add the points to the trail in the main QML with a timer. If these points were added to the model on the C++ side, how do I trigger a redraw on the QML map side?

Comment: did you see me comments above. Your solution is so close to what i need.

Comment: :The nodes of the history gets a different marker compared to current location marker, but every history marker is the same. The history marker is only a simple arrow png file that is rotated according to a heading/angle provided as part of the model. So if the asset i moving at180 degrees angle, the arrow.png is rotated 180degrees. PS: when I put the @eyllanesc in front and click on save edits, stackoverflow removes it)

Comment: The angle is additional data. When the point is recorded by the asset, it records the direction angle as well. So every point in the history will also have an angle associated with it.